# Hang up the call after x seconds after the called party has answered the call using ARI in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-ari

We've been using Asterisk's Dial plans for quite some time and now we've decided to switch to `ARI`. I'm wondering is there a way to hang up the call after x seconds after the called party has answered the call using `originate` or any other method from `/channels` resource in `ARI`. 
Note that I can do this using dial plan with `L(x:y:z)` or `S(duration)` functions but unfortunately can not find a way to use this feature in `Stasis` mode. here is a part of my dial plan in `extensions.conf`

```
exten => 8952XXXX,1,NoOp(${CALLERID(num)})
same => n,Set(ENDPOINT=${SIP_HEADER(X-Endpoint)})
same => n,Stasis(myapp,incoming,${EXTEN},unknown,unknown,none)
same => n,Hangup()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[context1]
exten => 8952XXXX,1,NoOp(${CALLERID(num)})
same => n,Set(__ENDPOINT=${SIP_HEADER(X-Endpoint)})
same => n,Dial(Local/${EXTEN}@context2/n,,L(x:y:z))
same => n,Hangup()
[context2]
exten => 8952XXXX,1,NoOp(${CALLERID(num)})
same => n,Stasis(myapp,incoming,${EXTEN},unknown,unknown,none)
same => n,Hangup()
```

Other option is use TIMEOUT(absolute)

Comment: This will modify the channel's endpoint number to number@context2. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, func_TIMEOUT. You always can save original channel name in variable.